# Probably silly - front end vs. back end for an app

Tags: mobile, xamarin, frontend, backend

Just a real basic question. I know what front end and back end development are...I think.

If I had an app, like a fitness tracking app that tracks your lifts and diet and things, I'd obviously need some kind of database. Apart from that, is there really any "back end" to speak of? There wouldn't be a server to communicate with or anything. It'd just be logging details in and putting them in the database.

If I had to divide an app like that into front and back ends, which parts would be which?

On a more specific note, are cross-platform frameworks like Xamarin a good option for development where you're splitting front and back ends between development teams or is native best for that?

Answer (score 1):

> If I had an app, like a fitness tracking app that tracks your lifts
>   and diet and things, I'd obviously need some kind of database. Apart
>   from that, is there really any "back end" to speak of? There wouldn't
>   be a server to communicate with or anything. It'd just be logging
>   details in and putting them in the database.
>
> If I had to divide an app like that into front and back ends, which
>   parts would be which?

FrontEnd: the app running on the iOS or Android device that has its own cache for the current user that is using the app.

Backend: the server that hosts the API and the database that will be storing all users data.

> On a more specific note, are cross-platform frameworks like Xamarin a
>   good option for development where you're splitting front and back ends
>   between development teams or is native best for that?

Any technology you pick for mobile development can have a front end and back end.

You could have a team that looks something like this:

Front End Team: Developing the iOS or Android app. (client)

BackEnd Team: Creating the Rest API, administering the database, Analytics etc..

Comment: Do you think that a server is really necessary for something like a fitness tracker app? I can't seem to think of why it'd be useful, since the client could really just write to the database immediately without working through a server.

Comment: if you don't have a server and all the data is in the local app, if a user deletes the app and then reinstalls it, he wont be able to retrieve his previous data from the "cloud". Other benefits of having a backend: - you can have some Business Logic on the API for CPU intensive tasks. - You can do analytics/stats with the data collected from users. - If you ever decide to target Android/Web then you can share business logic code on the API

Comment: If the back end is just a database though, couldn't the client just interact with the database directly? It'd perform all the tasks you mentioned except for the CPU-intensive tasks.